# How to downgrade svn working copy with svn version?

Tags: downgrade, svn

I have downgrade my svn from version 1.8 to 1.7.9. Now When i type command like:

```
svn info
svn up
```

or any other commands it give an error that:

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
(format 31)
```

I want use that copy only.How could i resolve this issue. I do not want to new checkout. Is there any solution for it.

Any idea..

Comment: Why did you change the version?

Comment: The solution is to use svn 1.8, but you downgraded. So, no, you will have to checkout again/.